# What do you call the action of alternatively walking and jogging to complete a Full Marathon?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing about my friend's first experience post completing a full marathon. Being her very first try at the endurance sport of long distance running, she couldn't complete the full distance, not at least by running. She had to complete it by walking and jogging alternatively (walking a few kms and jogging another few for the final ~12 odd kms). If I wanted to express this in a sentence, how can I best do it?

> Shree ________ her way to the finish line, completely exhausted and struggling for breath.

***Strolled*** and ***tiptoed*** seem to convey entirely different meanings to the above sentence. ***Struggled*** comes close but it would underwhelm what I am trying to say. I'd appreciate a lot if you could suggest an answer, specifically in the context of Marathons.

Comment: Do you want an answer from me? I always **limp**, but start to fly 2 or 3 miles before the finish line.

Comment: @deadrat- It's a nice option. However, it leans towards "unsteadily", which I am not fond of in this case... I will wait for some more options. Please post it as an answer. It makes a good candidate!

Comment: @Rathony - Nice! Being a marathon runner yourself, doesn't *limp* suggest that you met with an injury(teared muscle, pulled hamstring etc) during the course of the marathon? I'm not too sure.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Shree "gritted" her way to the finish line, completely exhausted and struggling for breath

Comment: @Elian surely it's "gritted her teeth"

Comment: Coming from a running family, we would always say 'jog-walked'.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but the "struggling for breath" part of your sentence reads awkward to me. Participants who are _run-walking_ will often change from jogging to walking when they are out of breath, and then go back to jogging after they have caught their breath again. I can see "struggling for breath" if she ran to the finish, but it seems out-of-place when she's walking in intervals. As for _limp_, that can imply stiffness as well as injury, so it might be a good word. I wouldn't necessarily assume one who _limped to the finish line_ had a sprain – it could be exhaustion.

Comment: @J.R. - All points noted. Will rephrase the sentence in my write-up accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps a [*half jog*](http://lolsnaps.com/funny/80438/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm no runner, I am allergic to any physical outdoor exercise but online I found the following

- Run-Walk

> The **walk-run** intervals in this plan remain consistent throughout (one minute of running and three minutes of walking) up until the race. The second program (**run-walk**) is for women who currently run-walk or who run shorter distances. **Run-walk** workouts are running-focused and intervals vary to help improve performance and speed.
>   [*Women's Running*](http://womensrunning.competitor.com/2012/11/training-tips/run-walk-half-marathon-training-plans_7838)

from the website [Walk Jog Run](http://www.walkjogrun.net/training/marathon/training-plan.cfm?planId=full-beg-rw)

> The **Newbie Run-Walk** Marathon Training Program is a very popular program for first-time marathoners and those who want to enjoy training with minimal risk of injury.

[New York Times](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/06/01/why-walk-breaks-help-you-run/)' article

> To train for my first marathon, I’m using the **“run-walk”** method, popularized by the distance coach Jeff Galloway, a member of the 1972 Olympic team.

The OP's sentence

> Shree **ran-walked** her way to the finish line, completely exhausted and struggling for breath.

Comment: Thanks for a great and pertinent answer. Although it seems to be a methodology for beginner Marathon runners, I can use the term figuratively to describe Shree's state. However, I will wait for some time before accepting! Hope that's OK.

Comment: No probs, someone who's into running will submit a better answer (if there's one).

Comment: Yeah, I'm no runner, but I've commonly seen "run/walk" or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

The word **Fartlek** describes the action of alternating speed:

> Fartlek is Swedish for "speed play," and that is exactly what it’s all
>   about. Unlike tempo and interval work, fartlek is unstructured and
>   alternates moderate-to-hard efforts with easy throughout.

<sup><sub>Source: [Runner's World](http://www.runnersworld.com/tag/fartlek)</sub></sup>

The previous quote suggests that this is a method of running, but in my own experience the following quote is more accurate:

> Fartlek, which means "speed play" in Swedish, is a training method
>   that blends continuous training with interval training. Fartlek runs
>   are a very simple form of a long distance run. Fartlek training “is
>   simply defined as periods of fast running intermixed with periods of
>   slower running." For some people, this could be a mix of jogging and
>   sprinting, but for beginners it could be walking with jogging sections
>   added in when possible.

<sup><sub>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fartlek)</sub></sup>

The idea is that as long as one *does not stop* it is a Fartlek. There is no strict structure, although one could impose a structure (e.g. sprint 100 meters, walk 100 meters, repeat) if one chooses. It could be just as valid to run as long as one is able, then walk or jog to recover.

---

To get back to your original example, we could restructure it a little bit to make it work around the noun Fartlek:

> Shree made her way to the finish line after a Fartlek, completely
>   exhausted and struggling for breath.

Comment: +1 for introducing a new term to me. **Fartlek** sounds funny in English, but it could well be apt for my scenario. Let me read more on this.

Comment: Interesting how other languages have these words but English does not. In German Fartlek is „Fahrtenspiel“ and the word OP is searching for would probably be „Laufmarsch“ (though it’s kind of a military term) which means literally “running march” and is a way for troops to cover long distances quickly by foot.

Comment: @Michael Technically, [fartlek is an English word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fartlek) of Swedish origin. Sort of like e.g. [mesa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mesa) which is of Spanish origin but still a valid English word meaning mostly the same thing.

Comment: @Snowman: Do native English speakers generally understand the meaning of Fartlek though? I’m not a native and the first mention of Fartlek I’ve encountered was in Daniel’s Running Formula by Jack Daniels where he introduces it as a “Swedish term translated as ‘speed play’.”.

Comment: @Michael depends on the context and the audience. I would classify "fartlek" as jargon: myself and my cross country and track teams in high school understood it, but I would not expect the general public to know the word. There are plenty of other examples, such as obscure medical terminology that English-speaking physicians would understand but laymen would be scratching their heads over.

Comment: @Michael I've never heard of it before myself.

Answer (score -1):

This is often referred to as interval (or sprint) training, i would expect the same when referring to using this during a marathon. So the strategy is "Internal running" a marathon.

This is a common technique used during long distance races.

Comment: Hi, Michael, how does this phrase fit in the OP's example sentence? Can you link a reference that can support your answer? Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.